# how to get current user name by user_id in buddypress?

Tags: buddypress

I want to display the user names by the reference of user id.

Is there any function like get_user_displaynme($userid)?
 (and one more Is there any shortcode to get group names?)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the very same `get_userdata` function of WordPress to code a specific function. Stick this in your `functions.php`:

```
function get_display_name($user_id) {
    if (!$user = get_userdata($user_id))
        return false;
    return $user->data->display_name;
}
```

So you can do something like:

```
$display_name = get_display_name($some_user_id);
echo $display_name;
```

Answer (score 3):

This may not be an answer to this question, but in the end I reached for this question when I am looking for a way to fetch the display name for the user through the ID

```
$user_displayname = get_user_by( 'id', $userid )->display_name ;
```

So maybe someone else may benefit from my answer

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice native function called [`get_user_by`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_by)

Comment: Please don't just add links, it's better to offer an explanation in your answer.